# Castle Windsor Interceptor on Caliburn View Model

Tags: castle-windsor, aop, caliburn, interceptor

I would like create own aspects with Castle Windsor Interceptor and apply on View Model classes.

As I said I use Caliburn MVVM framework and on DI I use Caste Windsor. Everything works good.

For example I created simple loggging interceptors, here is:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.Write("Log: Method Called: " + invocation.Method.Name);
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

This is simple View Model class - it is "tab item" :

```
public class TabViewModel : Screen, 
    ITabViewModel
{

}
```

When I configure IoC with Fluent API I would like apply this interceptor on View Model class.

```
       container.Register(Component
                    .For<LoggingInterceptor>()
                    .LifeStyle
                        .Singleton
                    .Named("LogAspect"));

        container.Register(Component
                    .For<ITabViewModel>()
                    .ImplementedBy<TabViewModel>()
                    .LifeStyle
                        .Transient
                    .Named("TabViewModel")
                    .Interceptors<LoggingInterceptor>());
```

When I tried pick view model from IoC:

```
var tabItem = IoC.Get<ITabViewModel>();
ActivateItem(tabItem);
```

I got this message:

> A default view was not found for Castle.Proxies.ITabViewModelProxy. 
>   Views searched for include:  Castle.Proxies.IITabViewModelProxy
>   Castle.Proxies.ITabViewModelProxys.IDefault
>   Castle.Proxies.ITabViewModelProxys.Default

Also I tried this way for interceptor applicaion.

```
[Interceptor(typeof(LoggingInterceptor))]
public class TabViewModel : Screen, 
    ITabViewModel
{

}
```

Ok, I know that Caliburn framework match View and View Model by naming convention.

When I try pick implementation of ITabViewModel I get ITabViewModelProxy and for ITabViewModelProxy I didn’t register any View.

Target of proxy is TabViewModel but I think problem is with naming mismatch.

I dont want rename ViewModel because I would like configure proxies from XML files.

So what is correct way?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
void Hack()
{
    var existing = ViewLocator.TransformName;
    ViewLocator.TransformName = (s, o) =>
                                existing(s.EndsWith("Proxy")
                                            ? s.Substring(0, s.Length - "Proxy".Length)
                                            : s, o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (and probably robust) is to suggest to Caliburn's ViewLocator to use not the type of view model's proxy but the type of the view model that's being proxied:

```
public static void AddViewLocatorRuleForProxiedViewModels()
{
    var originalViewTypeLocator = ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType;

    ViewLocator.LocateTypeForModelType = (modelType, displayLocation, context) =>
    {
        var viewModelType = modelType;

        var viewModelTypeName = viewModelType.FullName;
        if (viewModelTypeName.StartsWith("Castle.Proxies") && viewModelTypeName.EndsWith("Proxy"))
            viewModelType = viewModelType.BaseType;

        return originalViewTypeLocator(viewModelType, displayLocation, context);
    };
}
```